# How to complete this question with like clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

/*
BACKGROUND:

The following schema is a subset of a relational database of a grocery store
chain. This chain sells many products of different product classes to its
customers across its different stores. It also conducts many different
promotion campaigns.
The relationship between the four tables we want to analyze is depicted below:

```
       # sales                                # products
       +------------------+---------+         +---------------------+---------+
       | product_id       | INTEGER |>--------| product_id          | INTEGER |
       | store_id         | INTEGER |    +---<| product_class_id    | INTEGER |
       | customer_id      | INTEGER |    |    | brand_name          | VARCHAR |
  +---<| promotion_id     | INTEGER |    |    | product_name        | VARCHAR |
  |    | store_sales      | DECIMAL |    |    | is_low_fat_flg      | TINYINT |
  |    | store_cost       | DECIMAL |    |    | is_recyclable_flg   | TINYINT |
  |    | units_sold       | DECIMAL |    |    | gross_weight        | DECIMAL |
  |    | transaction_date | DATE    |    |    | net_weight          | DECIMAL |
  |    +------------------+---------+    |    +---------------------+-------
  |                                      |
  |    # promotions                      |    # product_classes
  |    +------------------+---------+    |    +---------------------+---------+
  +----| promotion_id     | INTEGER |    +----| product_class_id    | INTEGER |
       | promotion_name   | VARCHAR |         | product_subcategory | VARCHAR |
       | media_type       | VARCHAR |         | product_category    | VARCHAR |
       | cost             | DECIMAL |         | product_department  | VARCHAR |
       | start_date       | DATE    |         | product_family      | VARCHAR |
       | end_date         | DATE    |         +---------------------+---------+
       +------------------+---------+
 */
 /*
 PROMPT:
 -- What are the top five (ranked in decreasing order)
 -- single-channel media types that correspond to the most money
 -- the grocery chain had spent on its promotional campaigns?

 Single Media Channel Types are promotions that contain only one media type.

 EXPECTED OUPTUT:
 Note: Please use the column name(s) specified in the expected output in your solution.
 +---------------------------+------------+
 | single_channel_media_type | total_cost |
 +---------------------------+------------+
 | In-Store Coupon           | 70800.0000 |
 | Street Handout            | 70627.0000 |
 | Radio                     | 60192.0000 |
 | Sunday Paper              | 56994.0000 |
 | Product Attachment        | 50815.0000 |
 +---------------------------+------------+
 
-------------- PLEASE WRITE YOUR SQL SOLUTION BELOW THIS LINE ----------------

 */
```

```
Current answer: 

select media_type,sum(cost) from promotions
group by media_type order by sum(cost) desc
```

Comment: Since there is only one media_type value for each promotion row, by definition, there's no such thing as a multi-media channel type.  Can you clarify what is meant by that concept?

Comment: You've come up with a query. Does it work? If not, what have you done to debug it?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  There is a cost of the promotion and cost of goods sold based on the revenue earned for given sales.  Please EDIT your post and clarify, because some items may have low profit margins vs others.  So are you really looking for the best promotion cost, relative to the profit (sales – cost) of the goods sold?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   media_type AS single_channel_media_type , 
   ROUND(SUM(cost),4) AS total_cost
FROM 
   promotions
WHERE 
  media_type NOT LIKE '%,%'
GROUP BY 
  media_type
ORDER BY 
  total_cost DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Round is not necessary but as expected output has so.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select  media_type, sum(cost) 
From promotions
Where media_type not like '%,%'
Group by media_type 
Order by sum(cost) desc
Limit 5
```

Use `not like` to eliminate those promotions with more than one media_type, then limit your results to the top 5.